# SetExpressCheckout first call failed

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Since the API have changed all the times i try to pay with a developper test business i get an error like this :

```
array (
  'TIMESTAMP' => '2013-04-04T21:30:54Z',
  'CORRELATIONID' => 'c1929df7ab60a',
  'ACK' => 'Failure',
  'VERSION' => '97',
  'BUILD' => '5618210',
  'L_ERRORCODE0' => '10002',
  'L_SHORTMESSAGE0' => 'Security error',
  'L_LONGMESSAGE0' => 'Security header is not valid',
  'L_SEVERITYCODE0' => 'Error',
)
```

This is the call i make :

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?VERSION=97
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&
CANCELURL=http://url.com&
RETURNURL=http://url.com&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=78&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=SALE&
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CUSTOM=2856
```

But all the data in the API call is rightly filled.
I can't add a business account to my developper account.
Just befoire the API changes everything was fine, maybe i'm missing something ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem. I change the parameter name PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT to AMT and PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION to PAYMENTACTION and that works well. Hope so it works for you as well.

Comment: Keep in mind that the change that you are making is changing the variables from what you should be using, back to depreciated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your credentials you are passing over, try copying them again and make sure there is not extra white space before or after your credentials.

Comment: Hi, there where actually a typo on my username :/, so thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing "&" after https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?VERSION=97  <--- missing "&"

So you must change to : https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?VERSION=97&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&...

Hope this help, thank.